# How can I use isset method in php for two different posts?,

Tags: php, html, sql, isset

### I have two issets in one php file but it keeps on taking one of the posts only. So it is one or another! Here is the php part:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once'config/connect.php'; //database connection 
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {

    $add = mysql_query("UPDATE venue SET location='".$_POST['add']."'
WHERE vid = (select vid from user_venue where id = (select user_id from iangadot_user       
where username='".$_SESSION['username_profile']."' ))");    

}
if(isset($_POST['webb'])) {

    $webb = mysql_query("UPDATE venue SET web='".$_POST['webb']."'
WHERE vid = (select vid from user_venue where id = (select user_id from iangadot_user   
where username='".$_SESSION['username_profile']."' ))");    

}
 ?>
```

Html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <body>
 <form method="POST"> 
 <p>Address:</p> <input class = "field" name="add" placeholder= "<?php     
 if(isset($_SESSION['address'])) { echo $_SESSION['address']; } ?>" type="text" >
 <input class = "button"  type = "submit" Value = "Save"><br>
 <p>Website:</p> <input class = "field" name= "webb" placeholder = "<?php   
 if(isset($_SESSION['website'])) { echo $_SESSION['website']; } ?>" type="text">

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text input will always report a value in `$_POST`, possibly an empty string.

Conceptually, you allow the user to add both values, so it's up to you to prioritize one over the other or report an error in case both are filled.

Now to detect automatically which one was filled, you could simply test the value of the `$_POST` data.

```
if ($_POST['add'] != "" && $_POST['web'] != "") {
    error ("make up your mind!");
}
if ($_POST['add'] != "") { ....
if ($_POST['web'] != "") { ....
```

Comment: I need them to both work but what you're suggesting is saying make up your mind. I want them to be able to use both.

Comment: As long as you're sure only one of them will be set, it's fine. I would still leave an assertion in the PHP code, just to make sure the two values were not inadvertently set at the same time by the form.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
or die(mysql_error())
```

to the end of your query statements.  Chances are one of the queries has a syntax error.

Also, you really should be passing POST variables through at least 
     mysql_real_escape_string() 
Rather than inserting directly into your database.